# Date Validation on PreSaveAction in SharePoint 2010 list newform.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, list-form, newform

I need to validate few dates in my SP  2010 customnewform.aspx page.
I added the content editor web part, added the script but not able to get the result.

- ReqstDate : Should not be greater than Today's Date.
- End user can select yesterdays's date also but not tomorrow's date.
- By default I need to populate/bind the ReqstDate field with Today's date when the new form loads.
- Due By date : Should be greater than ReqstDate
- Orals Date : should not be greater than Due By Date

Is this possible throiugh jQuery or SPServices using PreSaveAction function

Comment: could you just share your code..

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can solve this with simple Validation settings on your list instead. Just from your requirements, you could do the following:

1. To populate the todays date in `ReqstDate` , set the default value on the column in the list to Today.
2. For the logic, go to list settings and add the following formula under Validation settings:

   `AND([ReqstDate]<=Today(); AND([Due By date]>[ReqstDate]; [Orals Date]<=[Due By date]))`

Depending on your local, the seperator could be `,` or `;` , in my example I used `;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.May I know,whether this list validation can be applied to different fields or  only a single  field ? if multiple fields are to be validated how to segregate these.

Comment: You'll have to nest all the fields in AND/OR etc. The outcome will be true/false for the form. The example have 3 checks, and when all are true the form is valid